# Cygwin-to-Linux cross-compiling gcc fails because it can not find a shared library, but it does not tell me which

Tags: gcc, cygwin, cross-compiling

I have obtained and installed a Cygwin-to-Linux cross-compiler from the [Cygwin Ports Project](http://sourceware.org/cygwinports/) and am trying to use it to compile a simple "Hello world"-program. Then this happens:

```
$i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc main.c
/usr/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g++.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Obviously, GCC can't find some DLL. Unforntunately, it does not print which and I do not know how I can find out.

This even happens when I try something as simple as running the preprocessor (through `i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -E`) over a C file that does nothing but `return 0`.

This GCC is version 4.7.2.

Does someone know how I can fix this? Or at least how I could find out the name of the library which can not be found?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why would you want to do this ? Why not just compile on the Linux target ?

Comment: My actual goal is to be able to build and debug remote C/C++ projects through Eclipse. I initially tried building remotely but it appears CDT does not really support that yet, so I thought cross-compiling on the Windows machine might be a solution.

Comment: It would probably be much easier just to run Linux locally ?

Comment: Absolutely, but we also want to build local Windows applications with the same Eclipse instance. I am trying to find out whether this is possible. Of course there are alternative solutions such as using a virtual machine, but this would be preferable.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - understand your motivation now - it sounds like you've got your work cut out for you though - good luck !

Comment: I don't know if ldd is available in cygwin, but you can try: ldd /usr/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g++.exe . On linux it displayed list of shared librairies needed by an executable

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://atratus.org/)? (plase notify @ me as I don't check for answers manually)